# Blender python align view to a specific axis

Tags: python, view, alignment, axis, blender

I'm using blender and I am currently scripting with python.

I have to generate a ZFunction considering three vertices that I select in the scene (what I did).
 Then I'd like to rotate manually (using the interface and not in the code) the ZFunction surface along an axis formed by two vertices.

For that I'd like to align my view orthogonally to this specific axis made from two vertices so that I can rotate the surface along this axis manually with the interface.

Is there a way to align a view considering a custom axis in a script?